# PowerQuery table to SQL Server by R Script error

Tags: r, powerquery

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wVN4.png

In Power Query Editor, the text string is: 123547126811
Why is the text string in SQL Server: 123547126811.0?

R Script:

```js
library(RODBC)
conn <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server}; server=localhost;Database=**;uid=uid;pwd=password")
odbcClearError(conn)
sqlSave(conn, dataset, tablename="tmp",rownames=FALSE, safer=FALSE, append=TRUE,fast=TRUE)
close(conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

using format function is ok:

```js
dataset$cust_id <- format(dataset$cust_id)
```